# Increasing training examples reduces accuracy for maximum entropy classifier

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

I am using MaxEnt part of speech tagger to pos tag classification of a language corpus. I know it from theory, that increasing training examples should generally improve the classification accuracy. But, I am observing that in my case, the tagger gives max f measure value if I take 3/4th data for training and rest for testing. If I increase the training data size by taking it to be 85 or 90℅ of the whole corpus, then the accuracy decreases. Even on reducing the training data size to 50℅ of full corpus, the accuracy decreases.

I would like to know the possible reason for this decrease in accuracy with increasing training examples.

Comment: It looks like your testing data is not fixed (when you increase the training data size). Either you are using 1/4 of data as testing or you are using 1/10 of your data. This is not apple-to-apple comparison.  Can you fix your testing data and measure the performance again? Or you can do k-fold cross validation, with an increasing of k. and report what did you see.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that in the reduced testing set you selected extreme samples and add more general samples into your train set then you reduced the number of testing samples that your model knows them.